# HttpWebResponse - The Operation timed out

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to download and save the favicon for various websites. For the majority the following code works. However, I have a problem with some urls. for example:

`https://www.bestbuy.com/favicon.ico` [bestbuy](https://www.macys.com/favicon.ico), 
`https://www.macys.com/favicon.ico` [macys](https://www.bestbuy.com/favicon.ico)

I can open these urls in my default browser (firefox) without any problems.

This is the code I'm using to do the `HttpWebRequest` and where I get the exception.

This is how I do the WebRequest

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Timeout = 10000;
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
request.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.UserAgent = "Application name here";
response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Any ideas why the example urls time out (again, most work fine).
`

Comment: Did you try not to set the UserAgent property at all?

Comment: Yes, it all seems hit and miss to me - some web sites want it, others are very specific ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting blocked by your useragent. Send something a browser would send. I used this:

`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.75 Safari/537.36`

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Timeout = 10000;
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | 
DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
request.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.75 Safari/537.36";
response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```